# HTML open fresh new window again on image onclick

Tags: javascript, html, image

Trying different options like
I have page opened in new window
below opens in newtab

```
 <a href="imageurl" target="_blank">
        <img src="imageurl" style="width: 50%; height: 220px;">
  </a>
```

Below overrides the current window

```
<img src="imageurl" style="width: 50%; height: 220px;" onclick="window.open(this.src)">
```

Looking to open in new window again. Please suggest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To trigger a new window instead of a new tab (something you should generally be reluctant to do) you need to specify some [window features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features) which the browser won't apply to a tab.

Setting `resizable` is sufficient in Chrome. I haven't tested in other browsers.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://placekitten.com/100/100" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
</a>
```

JS:

```
const openInNewWindow = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const {href, target} = event.currentTarget;
  const features = "resizable";
  window.open(href, target, features);
};


document.querySelector("a")
  .addEventListener("click", openInNewWindow);
```

(Don't bind click event listeners to images, they aren't designed as interactive controls. Users who depend on (for example) a screen reader or a keyboard focus to interact with a document will find it difficult or impossible to trigger a click on an image. Use semantic markup. If you are linking something, use a link, then enhance with JS.)

Comment: Thanks for the help.This is how i have tested but still opens in tab and we are expecting popup window<script>
const openInNewWindow = event => {
   event.preventDefault();
   const {href, target} = event.currentTarget;
   const features = "resizable";
   window.open(href, target, features);
 };
 document.querySelector("teststst")
   .addEventListener("click", openInNewWindow);
</script>
html

<a id="teststst" href="http://placekitten.com/100/100" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
</a>

Comment: Well `teststst` will match any `<teststst>` elements in your HTML document and you shouldn't have any of those … so why do you have that?

Comment: Can i add onclick js function from anchor tag.. ? please tell what to add in called function..I have tried by putting document.querySelector("a"),still opens in tab..

Comment: tried window.location.replace('url') this overrides the current window too...Onclick one more pop up window should open with the image showing..

Comment: I'm lost. Why are you looking at location.replace? My answer doesn't mention it (for good reason!). Just do what I said in the answer.

Comment: Yes tested from the answer this opens in tab not a popup window

Comment: It's a new window when I test it: https://i.postimg.cc/13jF1jKb/2020-11-11-08-53-57.gif

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I was putted java script beginning of body tag thats why element was not detecting..it worked.Thanks lot :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try like

```
window.open(this.src,"_blank");
```

Comment: No. That has no control over if a new window or tab is opened.